# Logical AND in bash script

Tags: shell-script

Neither of these options seem to work. What am I doing wrong? (`leapb`, `leapc` and `iyr` are integer values)

```
if [[ $leapb -eq $iyr && $leapc -ne $iyr ]]; then
  leap=0
fi
```

Alternatively,

```
if [[ $leapb -eq $iyr ]] && [[ $leapc -ne $iyr ]]; then
  leap=0
fi
```

When running this using `iyr=1979`, `leapb=1900`, `leapc=1600`, the script doesn't reach the `leap=0` line, with error msg stating `-eq: unary operator expected` .

Comment: In what sense do they "not work"? What are the values of the variables, what are you expecting would happen, and what happens?

Comment: Expectation: if ((leapb = iyr) and (leapc /= iyr) then leap=0

Comment: And what are the actual values of the variables?

Comment: Outcome: the script doesn't reach the leap=0 line, with error msg stating    -eq: unary operator expected

Comment: Example: iyr=1979, leapb=1900, leapc=1600

Comment: and line before has leap=1

Comment: I can't reproduce that error with those values and that code (neither variation of the code).  Both variations are syntactically correct.

Comment: thanks a mil, then the error is in my logic and not the code

Answer (score 1):

With a simplified version of your code:

```
[[ $a -eq $b ]]
```

There is no error with any value of `a` and `b`, even strings, empty, or unset.

An older version of `[[` is `[`, but even that, properly quoted:

```
[ "$a" -eq "$b" ]
```

Only complains when the value inside `a` or `b` is an string (or empty/unset):

```
./script: line 13: [: StringInsideA: integer expression expected
```

Which means that the actual code you are testing is both using `[` and **not** quoting the variable expansions (bad idea):

```
[ $a -eq $b ]
```

In which case, if `a` is empty/unset while `b` has some value (or viceversa) the error reported will be:

```
./script: line 14: [: -eq: unary operator expected
```

Conclusion: please use the `[[` version of the test (while in bash,ksh,zsh).

## logic

For the values you report:

Understand that if `leapb=1900` and `iyr=1979` (that is **not equal**) the first test fails and the `leap=0` will never be executed no matter what the value of `leapc` might be.

The only way to get to execute `leap=0` is that `leapb=iyr` and then `leapc` is **not** equal to `iyr`.

## simpler

If all you want to do is to detect when a year is leap, use this:

```
leap=$(( y>0 && ( y%4==0 && y%100>0 || y%400==0 ) ))
```

In this formula, leap will be 1 for leap years and 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the error in `bash` given your code.  With the given values, the code would not reach `leap=0` since `$iyr` and `$leapb` are not equal.

However, if I modify it like this:

```
if [ $leapb -eq $iyr ] && [ $leapc -ne $iyr ]; then
    leap=0
fi
```

then this would produce

```
[: -eq: unary operator expected
```

if `$leapb` is an empty string.

With the `[[ ... ]]` syntax, the test would fail silently though.

Related reading:

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)